# Best solution for home network in a Town House

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, signal-strength

I live in a townhouse. The ground floor has an office and is where the ADSL comes into the house. First floor has the living room, kitchen and top floor is where the bedrooms are located. The house has structured cabling so at the moment I have the ADSL router on the first floor. It is patched back to the ADSL point on the ground floor. I have a signal booster on the ground floor as signal strength in the office is not strong enough. The SSID on the ground floor (via signal booster) ends in _EXT in order to differentiate it from the main SSID. Is it possible to change the setup, perhaps with a Wireless Access Point, so the SSID is the same all through the house without losing signal strength? I want to move the wireless router downstairs to connect it directly to the ADSL point but doing this will impact the living floors (1 and 2). The solution on the 1st floor needs to include ethernet ports as I have a NAS drive. I just need someone to point me in the right direction. Please help?